# Sorting a List<Asset> by a date

Tags: apex, loop, collection, iteration

I have fetched assets sorted by date using SOQL query. When I do for(Asset a:lstAsset) and add a to a list, the sort order from the SOQL query is lost.

I want the sort order to be retained. Is there a way? And can someone explain how List iterator for loop works? Is it the best one to use or is there a better way?

Comment: How do you know that the sort order has been lost? Lists store things in the order that you insert them in, so if your List appears to be out-of-order, it's because you initially put them into the list out-of-order  (or you've called `List.sort()`).

Comment: Also, if the only purpose of your loop is to insert records into a list, you should consider just directly assigning the query results to your `List<Asset>` instead. e.g. `List<Asset> myAssets = [SELECT Id, <other fields> FROM Asset WHERE <conditions> ORDER BY myDate]`

Comment: hi @yeselkay, please accept an answer if it helped you resolve your question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MyClass {
  private AssetWrapper[] awList = new List<AssetWrapper>();
  public class AssetWrapper implements Comparable {
     private Asset a;
     public AssetWrapper(Asset a) {this.a = a;}
     public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        // needs bus logic to decide if null date is < non null date or vice-versa
        AssetWrapper ctA = (AssetWrapper) compareTo;
        if (ctA.someDate < this.a.someDate) return +1;
        if (ctA.someDate > this.a.someDate) return -1;
        return 0; 
  }

   public void getAssets() {
     for (Asset a: [select ....])
        awList.add(new AssetWrapper(a));
   }

   public void addAsset(Asset a) {awList.add(new AssetWrapper(a));}
   public void sortAssets() {awList.sort();}
}
```

Notes

- global modifier not required
- you can use inner class

Comment: You need some null checks. Also once those are done you can youse your favorite expression syntax...ternary! Doesn't the `Comparable` interface require the parameter type to be `Object`, too?

Comment: right you are re: `Object`;

Comment: @cropredy, could you add null check to you example, please? Is it simple `if (ctA.someDate == null) return -1;` and `if (this.a.someDate == nul) return 1;`?

Comment: @Eduard - this is up to you to decide if nulls sort first or last but the approach in your comment is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Reference from [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_list_sorting_sobject.htm)

To implement a custom sort order for sObjects in lists, create a wrapper class for the sObject and implement the Comparable interface. The wrapper class contains the sObject in question and implements the compareTo method, in which you specify the sort logic.

Below example shows how to create a wrapper class for Opportunity. The implementation of the compareTo method in this class compares two opportunities based on the Amount field—the class member variable contained in this instance, and the opportunity object passed into the method.

```
global class OpportunityWrapper implements Comparable {

    public Opportunity oppy;

    // Constructor
    public OpportunityWrapper(Opportunity op) {
        oppy = op;
    }

    // Compare opportunities based on the opportunity amount.
    global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        // Cast argument to OpportunityWrapper
        OpportunityWrapper compareToOppy = (OpportunityWrapper)compareTo;

        // The return value of 0 indicates that both elements are equal.
        Integer returnValue = 0;
        if (oppy.Amount > compareToOppy.oppy.Amount) {
            // Set return value to a positive value.
            returnValue = 1;
        } else if (oppy.Amount < compareToOppy.oppy.Amount) {
            // Set return value to a negative value.
            returnValue = -1;
        }

        return returnValue;       
    }
}
```

Below example provides a test for the OpportunityWrapper class. It sorts a list of OpportunityWrapper objects and verifies that the list elements are sorted by the opportunity amount.

```
@isTest 
private class OpportunityWrapperTest {
    static testmethod void test1() {
        // Add the opportunity wrapper objects to a list.
        OpportunityWrapper[] oppyList = new List<OpportunityWrapper>();
        Date closeDate = Date.today().addDays(10);
        oppyList.add( new OpportunityWrapper(new Opportunity(
            Name='Edge Installation',
            CloseDate=closeDate,
            StageName='Prospecting',
            Amount=50000)));
        oppyList.add( new OpportunityWrapper(new Opportunity(
            Name='United Oil Installations',
            CloseDate=closeDate,
            StageName='Needs Analysis',
            Amount=100000)));
        oppyList.add( new OpportunityWrapper(new Opportunity(
            Name='Grand Hotels SLA',
            CloseDate=closeDate,
            StageName='Prospecting',
            Amount=25000)));

        // Sort the wrapper objects using the implementation of the 
        // compareTo method.
        oppyList.sort();

        // Verify the sort order
        System.assertEquals('Grand Hotels SLA', oppyList[0].oppy.Name);
        System.assertEquals(25000, oppyList[0].oppy.Amount);
        System.assertEquals('Edge Installation', oppyList[1].oppy.Name);
        System.assertEquals(50000, oppyList[1].oppy.Amount);
        System.assertEquals('United Oil Installations', oppyList[2].oppy.Name);
        System.assertEquals(100000, oppyList[2].oppy.Amount);

        // Write the sorted list contents to the debug log.
        System.debug(oppyList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your implementation could certainly be more concise, but the bigger issue with your code is that it will throw a `NullPointerException` if any record's `Amount` field is null (and OP wanted to sort on a `Date` field` anyway...).